# Second date Picker should show dates after the date selected in first date picker

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I have two date pickers. In first I'm selecting a date, and I want second date picker to show the dates after that particular date. Previous dates should be disabled.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Please post some code of what you have done so far. In general, I can answer in a simple way. After the selection of first date picker, get that date and set that date as the minimum date for the second picker and then initialize the second picker.

Comment: try setting value from the first picker and set the minimum date of the next date picker .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use minimum date property of the date picker to disable the all date before the minimum date. The date picker would also allow you to define range as minimum and maximum date so that it can show the date from minimum to maximum date range and remaining all other date will be disabled in picker view.

Answer (score 0):

**swift 3**

```
    datePickerEndDate.minimumDate = datePickerStartDate.date
```